# What is a breakpoint in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I was scrolling through and accidentally clicked the left side and it created one. When I went to delete it I read the name and I am curious as to what it does? Is it for quick navigation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint

Comment: A quick Google would have give you this: "In software development, a breakpoint is an intentional stopping or pausing place in a program, put in place for debugging purposes. It is also sometimes simply referred to as a pause.", from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breakpoints are for debugging!

Answer (score 2):

You need breakpoints for debugging.

checkout:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint